# ASP.NET MVC return a different view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a view which contains a form, the form posts and the data gets processed etc, then I want to return the view Index, so return view("Index");

however this will then complain about my ViewData not existing, I get the feeling that the controller code under Index() isn't being processed which adds the list it requires to the ViewData, anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

edit: Apparently it's done to prevent recursion.. in which case, I'm lost as to what to do without repeating all my ViewData stuff both Controllers

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I think you should have two actions: one that processes the form submission, and another one that collects data for the view.
Once the form has been processed, you call `return RedirectToAction("Index")` and you are done.
I hope I understood what you meant by this.

Comment: +1 absolutely the way to go, read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get for more details on benefits of this approach.

Comment: how about without redirecting? return View("Index")

Comment: @CodeClimber. I have a bit similar scenario. I have a partial view in Index page. Partial view submits the form. on form submission data is stored in database. I want to show the latest data on the Index page. when i tried your approach i get this error "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List but the dictionary requires a model item of type 'UnderstandingPartialViews.Models.abc'"

Comment: @Luckyy, we can redirect to action from one controller to another too, via by RedirectToAction

Answer (score 6):

If your Index method on the controller does a `return View("Index");` then just call the Index method with any parameters it requires.  Then the method will populate the ViewData reuired by the Index View.